# Unity: How to deserialize json string into class?

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I am new to unity, i am learning how to make a unity app with Facebook integration using the Facebook SDK for Unity. I have been trying to make a json result from a graph request that is executed in a class method from unity, my problem is that everytime i try to access a propery of the supposed deserialized json to class it throws this error:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

This error is thrown at the line where i am trying to access the property and not where the object is created.. this happens with both json utilities from Facebook and Unity, i've no idea how to properly transform a json data into a class, the code i have is this:

```
private void FbGetPhotos() {
    actionText.text = "Requesting photos";

    FB.API("/me/photos", HttpMethod.GET, result => {
        NodesResult nodesResult = NodesResult.FromJSON(result.RawResult);

        Debug.Log(nodesResult.data.Count);
    });
}
```

NodesResult class

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

namespace classes {
    public class NodesResult {
        public List<object> data;
        public object paging;

        public static NodesResult FromJSON(string raw) {
            return JsonUtility.FromJson<NodesResult>(raw);
        }
    }
}
```

JSON String

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "created_time": "2018-08-12T08:07:35+0000",
      "name": "Horas de horas para lograr esto Javier Andres Mura Rios Estoy orgulloso.",
      "id": "1919500911450147"
    }
  ],
  "paging": {
    "cursors": {
      "before": "QVFIUnpNaTZAqSW1NMDJya0ZAtWUZAiRWxRWW1lUHdmYy1rVERHaldsVllXSFBab0h4YW1HcEtXTmhNdW0tNGxVVjRQbXotdHo3alBvUzRUa09TaVJiVzJYc2ln",
      "after": "QVFIUnpNaTZAqSW1NMDJya0ZAtWUZAiRWxRWW1lUHdmYy1rVERHaldsVllXSFBab0h4YW1HcEtXTmhNdW0tNGxVVjRQbXotdHo3alBvUzRUa09TaVJiVzJYc2ln"
    }
  }
}
```

Like i said, the error is thrown when i try to access the property, in this case is where the Debug.Log is.

**Note:** I know there are many examples out there but none of them worked for me, also the facebook example handles the data using Dictionary object only, but i believe that using Dictionary only would make the code a bit hard to understand, also this is likely my first time parsing a json string in C# so i am very interested on what is the recommended way to properly parse the json string into a class and sub-classes

Comment: @ScottChamberlain What problem is happening, why the problem is happening when i am accesing and not when creating the object?, i really tried to find an answer by myself before asking this in here

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Both the editor and unity display that the error comes at the line where the Debug.Log is, as said in the question

Comment: Are you sure that the JSON you received from FB complies with the class structure of `NodesResult`?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya yes, i edited the question showing how the json is

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I edited the question to show the json string

Comment: Please show us what the debugger shows for the value of `nodesResult` when you put a breakpoint in after it. Also show what the debugger shows as the value of `result.RawResult` inside the debugger. (also clean up your old comments a lot of previous comments where deleted when they where no longer relevent due to your updates)

Comment: put the the json [here](http://json2csharp.com/), generate the objects. Read the troubleshooting section in the duplicate if you have issues. If you still can't fix it, edit your question with the latest non-working code

Comment: @ScottChamberlain `result.RawResult` is the exact value as shown in the edited question as a string, also @Programmer i will try that tool